# Rails searching through => model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a main model called 'Notes' which has the following:

```
attr_accessible :name, :label_tokens
has_many :labelships
has_many :labels, :through => :labelships
attr_reader :label_tokens
```

So basically the Note_id & Label_id are kept in the Labelships table.

What i would like to do is create a list of distinct Labels and create a link on each value to the respective Note.

Example: Note 'mynote' has a label of 'git' associated through the labelship table, i would like Git to appear on a list of other labels, and then when i click on git, i get a list of Notes that have the label 'git' on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following models:

```
class Note
  has_many :labelships
  has_many :labels, :through => :labelships
end

class Labelships
  belongs_to :note
  belongs_to :label
end

class Label
  has_many :labelships
  has_many :notes, :through => :labelships
end
```

Now given a label, you can get its notes as follows:

```
label.notes
```

To exclude the note in hand:

```
label.notes.where("id != ?", note.id)
```

Comment: do i include that in the model or controller, can you show me a quick example.

Comment: It depends on how you are accessing the list, if you are trying to get the list of notes based on a label on hand you can use `label.notes`. If you are trying to get the sibling notes for a note using a given label add a function to Note model.

Comment: What i want is have a for each list of labels, so when i click on those labels they'll provide me a list of notes with that associated label.